# Redirection to an action with razor by clicking into button

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an asp.net mvc4 application. in which i have to put a n image with the url to an action:

```
<a href="@Html.ActionLink("Retour","Retour","Client")"><img src="~/Content/images/home-icon.png" /></a>
```

but an error of invalid url is appears. 
So what is the reason of this error? how can i fix my code?

Comment: use @Html.ActionLink("Retour",... only

Comment: how? i need the redirection to action be by clicking into button none a simple link

Comment: Where does the error appears? When you compile or do you mean the image isn't visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use these ways
**Method 1:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Retour","Retour","Client",null, new { @class="background" })
```

CSS :

```
a.background
{
    background: url(../Images/image.gif) no-repeat top left;
     display: block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
<a href='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")'>
    <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/image.gif")' />
</a>
```

**Method 3:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Retour","Retour","Client" , new {
      style = "background: url('../../Content/Images/image.gif') no-repeat center right;display:block; height:24px; width:24px;"
} )
```